# Controlling the Pi by an Android phone through a webpage

Tags: wifi, android

I want to control my raspberry pi from my android phone using a webpage that I will create myself, the idea is that I'll write a program both for my phone and for my raspberry pi. Then Pi will then be controlled over that specific webpage that again get signals from the Phone. The Pi will get its wireless internet connection from a Wifi subscription dongle, so the Pi will get internet from almost everywhere in Norway. This is where I want the pi to get signals from my phone telling it to light a lamp for example.

Will this work with the pi? Or do I need to buy LogiPi FPGA board to make this possible? 
And what Launguage should I use to create the program in the pi? Java or Phyton?

Answer (score 1):

> The Pi will get its wireless internet connection from a Wifi subscription dongle

I don't know much about these, but if it works by connecting to large WLANs in urban areas (something tells me that's not actually "most of Norway" although it may be "a lot of places where most people live"), it is going to be a hassle for you to get an external IP that can be reached from outside whatever WLAN the pi is on.  If your phone uses a data plan, it will be outside that network.  I know that there are "dynamic DNS" services around which manage the IP associated with a domain name dynamically, but for that you'd first need a domain name.  I also don't know if they will work with your subscription service.

**If it doesn't work that way** -- i.e., if it actually uses a mobile network like a phone does, things may be a bit easier, but you will still not likely have a stable IP (it will change periodically), meaning you still have an issue with finding an address to reach the pi from outside.  One solution to that is, again, a dynamic DNS service.

If you have a third server somewhere that does have a stable IP (e.g., a VPS), you could keep that updated with the pi's current IP and check it from the phone, or relay traffic directly to the pi.